# What is "ownership in the individual Series of a Series LLC that owns a home asset"?

Tags: rental-property, real-estate, limited-liability-company, investment

I am looking into [Arrived Homes](https://arrivedhomes.com/), a real-estate investment site.  (No affiliation.)  I am trying to determine, if you invest, what happens when the home is sold.  Their [answer](https://help.arrivedhomes.com/en/articles/4496432-who-legally-has-ownership-of-the-house) to the question "Who legally has ownership of the house?" is not clear to me.

> When you purchase shares in an Arrived home offering, you are directly
> buying ownership in the individual Series of a Series LLC that owns
> that home asset. So if for example, you purchase 1% of the shares in a
> single home offering, you would then be entitled to 1% of the economic
> interests of the asset over time, which may include income from rent
> or property value appreciation.

Can someone please paraphrase the answer in laymen terms?  Is this normal jargon, or is it intentionally unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series LLC is a single LLC filing with secretary of state where it is incorporated that includes many numbered sub-LLCs which are identical to each other in all internal governance respects except ownership.

It is implied that this particular venture uses one sub-LLC per house.

They are trying to say that if you invest x% in a single sub-LLC that owns a single house, then you own x% of the distributable income derived from that house (e.g. from rent net of management fees and operating expenses a.k.a. carrying costs) and that you also own x% of the net equity proceeds upon the sale (or other form of liquidation such as an eminent domain condemnation or insurance proceeds from a completely destroyed home) of the house after payment of any loans and closing costs.

They don't reuse the sub-LLC once the house is sold. They just discard it.